# Relating Users with Facebook Login and Parse.com

Tags: mysql, sql, database, facebook, parse-platform

I want users in an app that I am thinking of creating to have a default image upon signing up/logging in, so integrating Facebook Login makes sense. But, I also want to have a way to relate users and have them be "friends" on my app.

How would I implement such a functionality with Parse.com as my backend? The only way I can currently think about implementing friends using parse is by the username. But, if my users log in with Facebook, they will not have a username for my app.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check if https://parse.com/questions/how-can-i-find-parse-users-that-are-facebook-friends-with-the-current-user  does not help a bit

Comment: @Qiqi that's not quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: When they log in by facebook you can take username/name from facebook data, it is not obvious what is the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @PetrV, Right now, my app does not use Facebook login. I am able to have the functionality of adding friends on my app via Parse usernames. But, signing up for another app is tedious, so I would like to integrate Facebook. I also want users to have default images. But, with Facebook, there is no Parse username. Thus, how will I able to connect users on my app by using Facebook login? Does that make it clear?